# Cleverbot Twitch SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: twitch

Hello has anyone got this working, It connects but comes back with this error.
I was wondering if anyone would like to help me solve this problem or guide me and change it to cleverbot.com instead of cleverbot io.
I am not a programmer and have limited knowledge of this
I basically want the bot to chat to my users in twitch chat with natural responses not pre typed hence why i would like to use cleverbot

https://libraries.io/npm/clevererbot-twitch

[image]

Comment: Please provide relevant code snippets.

Comment: https://libraries.io/npm/clevererbot-twitch

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the help section on how to post a question and provide a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).